# Grails: Custom ID - Year Followed by Incrementing Number

Tags: oracle, grails, customization

I'm trying to figure out how best to implement a custom ID for certain Grails domain model classes.  The requirement is to have IDs that start with the year and are followed by a dash and a incrementing number (that resets to 0 in the next year).  So IDs would be:

```
2014-1
2014-2
2014-3
```

The actual part of using a custom ID is not a problem.  Where I'm getting stuck is figuring out the best way to always increment my ID.  Normally the database handles incrementing an ID and making sure it's unique.  However, since I'll be using custom IDs I guess I need to handle that.  Is it possible to somehow get the database involved to do some of this unique testing and incrementing?  What's the usual approach for solving this problem?

Btw, I'm running an Oracle database on the back end in case that matters.

Comment: Your app won't work in a cluster with id generation like this. Donal has a good suggestion IMO - if you need such column the add it, but not as id.

Answer (score 0):

If at all possible you should store this as a unique property of the domain class, but let the database generate the ID value. If you absolutely must use this as the ID, then the Grails docs that describe how to [customizes the way the identifier for a domain class is generated](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html) should get you started.

Comment: Thanks, but that's the part I already know about ... my question is specifically about how to manage sequentially increasing numbers that must stay unique in the database.